# Unity3d character body length

Tags: unity-game-engine, character, unityscript

I am having trouble using Unity3D (js).
I would like to add gameObjects behind my character (a bit like the snake game I guess). I just dont know how to set a different position each time. Ps: My character is in constant movemement. Here is my script:

```
var lenght : int = 0;
var LenghtCharacter: Rigidbody;
var character:Rigidbody;

function AddLenght(amount : int) {
    lenght += amount;
    for (var i=0; i <= lenght; i++) {
    var oneLenght = Instantiate(
        LenghtCharacter, 
        character.transform.position - character.transform.forward * (0.3 * i), 
        character.transform.rotation);
    }  
}
```

I call this function when my character collides with an 'asteroid' =]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A SpringJoint is the perfect component to fluidly achieve the exact functionality you are describing:
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-SpringJoint.html